# How to read "\'-alert(1)//" using PyYAML?

Tags: python, yaml

In yaml file, there is a string:

```
"\'-alert(1)//"
```

I used the following code to read the file:

```py
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        yaml_data = yaml.safe_load(file) # also tried unsafe_load
```

I got the error message:

```
found unknown escape character "'"
```

How can I read this string successfully?

Comment: Given that it's invalid YAML, you can't. Why do you have this randomly incorrectly escaped string in the first place?

Comment: @deceze This is from a waf test tool: https://github.com/wallarm/gotestwaf/blob/master/testcases/owasp/xss-scripting.yml.

Comment: Seems to me that the YAML parser used by this project (https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) may incorrectly accept this as valid, when it shouldn't be…?!

Comment: @deceze If I want use PyYAML to parse, how can I modify the string to make it valid and accepted as \'-alert(1)//?

Comment: Don't escape the single quote. If you want the backslash, use `"\\'-alert(1)//"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the backslash to escape some special characters in double quoted scalars in YAML, but the single quote is not an [escapable character](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.1/#id2776092). Therefore your YAML is invalid.

Either escape the backslash ( `"\\'-alert(1)//"` ) or remove the double quotes ( `\'-alert(1)//` ) for the same result after loading. You can also remove the backslash ( `"'-alert(1)//"` ), which loads to a different result.